# Delete a Node in Linked list given access to only that Node

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I am working on this code challenge:

> ### Delete a Node in Linked list given access to only that Node
>
> A linked list is a collection of nodes. Where each node contains some data address of the next node, if it is the last node then it contains the data only. This way we can access all the nodes if we have the address of first node.
>
> Now the task is that given a pointer to some node in a linked list, delete it if it is not the last node of the list.
>
> Complete the function `deleteNodeK()` which takes the address of the node of a linked list as a parameter and delete this node from the list. (If given node is last node of list then do nothing.)

I'm trying to delete the node by copying the `node.next` data into the current node data and then changing the pointer of current node to `node.next.next`.

```
def deleteKNode(node):
  if node.next == None:
    return
  else:
    node.data = node.next.data
    node.next = node.next.next
```

But it's giving me the following error:

> `if node.next == None:`
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

[image]

My complete code snippet below:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

def printList(node):
  while (node != None):
    print(node.data, end=' ');
    node = node.next;
    
def insertEnd(head, data):
  new_node = Node(data)
  if head is None:
    head = new_node
    return head;
    
  last = head
  while (last.next):
    last = last.next
    
  last.next =  new_node
  return head

def deleteKNode(node):
  if node.next == None:
    return
  else:
    node.data = node.next.data
    node.next = node.next.next


# Don't edit this function
def main():
    t = int(input().strip());
    for i in range(t):
      head = None;
      n = int(input().strip());
      k = 0;
      if(n!=0):
        inp = input().strip().split();
        for j in inp:
          head = insertEnd(head,int(j.strip()));
      k = int(input().strip());
      node = head;
      if(k>0):
        while(k>0):
          node = node.next;
          k = k-1;
      deleteKNode(node);
      printList(head);
      print();

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main();
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usercode/file.py3", line 54, in <module>
    main();
  File "/usercode/file.py3", line 50, in main
    deleteKNode(node);
  File "/usercode/file.py3", line 29, in deleteKNode
    if node.next == None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: @kcsquared I entered every single detail of the question  :)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error; running that code with the inputs you give just prints '1 2 4' without any error.

Comment: I attached an image link in above post which is showing the error, can u please check it once , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that `deleteKNode` is called with a `None` argument. Since your main code cannot be changed (according to the code comments there), we must assume that `deleteNode` could really be called with `None`.

So change your `if` condition as follows:

```
def deleteKNode(node):
  if node is None or node.next is None:
    return
  else:
    node.data = node.next.data
    node.next = node.next.next
```

Be aware (as explained also in the code challenge) that when `node` is the last node of the list, this function does not delete that node -- nor could it.

Comment: Now I understand it. I was missing this if condition to check if node is None or not. Thank you so much. It worked

Comment: Yes, its done, thanks again :)